# How to achieve Angular barcode scanner as a PWA?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, barcode-scanner

I need to read barcode(not QR-code) from the web interface(uploading image) as well as the mobile camera(take photo and upload).

I have tried this with [ngx-barcode-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-barcode-scanner). But it is throwing the below exception in web interface neither it does not work on mobile as well.

> core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotFoundError: Requested device not found
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
>           at zone.js:892
>           at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
>           at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>           at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>           at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)

Any idea how to achieve this? Also, I have done reading QR-CODE functionality by following this [link](https://blog.cloudboost.io/how-to-build-a-qr-code-reader-in-your-non-native-angular-web-app-806e1e053fe9) and it works well. My angular version is 6.

Comment: It seems that your camera could not be found. Can you try the [quaggajs example](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/examples/live_w_locator.html) to see if it can work with a vanilla JS version ?

Comment: could you please help how to achieve the same with angular 6+?

Comment: Ya it working with vannilajs version. Also it is working with ngx bar code scanner.
But the ngx bar code scanner is scanning the barcodes of "code_128" and one or two other types. is it possible to make the ngx bar code scanner to scan atleast 5-6 types of bar code?
` <barcode-scanner-livestream type="code_128" (valueChanges)="onValueChanges($event)">

how can we modify the type to scan some other bar code types also?`